# TransactionScope TransactionAborted Exception - BeginCommit()?

Tags: transactionscope

TimeoutException problems.

Context: Visual Studio 2010

The problem: I occasionally (ca once a day on a program that runs once an hour) get an exception
that I do not understand.

This is the exception:

```
Exception message : The transaction has aborted.
Exception Source : System.Transactions
Exception Trace  :    at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.BeginCommit(InternalTransaction tx, Boolean asyncCommit, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()
   at JDTranslation_K4_ReadEmails.Form1.ReadEmailDetails(EmailMessage emMessage, String strUserName, String strAccountName)
Exception Target : Void BeginCommit(System.Transactions.InternalTransaction, Boolean, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
```

The exception happens typically after a transaction that has lasted 25-30 minutes.

I have set up my transaction to last 5 hours (see below), so I do not understand at all why
it can time out.

And I am somewhat concerned: I know that some of the data are committed to the
database - can I trust that they all are? (It is nearly impossible to verify by
investigating the data.)

The program (part of the function) looks approximately like this:

```
//INSTANTIATE THE TRANSACTION SCOPE
TransactionOptions option = new TransactionOptions();
//SET THE ISOLATION LEVEL AND THE TIMEOUT DURATION
option.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
option.Timeout = new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0);

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, option))
{
try{
// do some select/update/insert/delete stuff on both connections,
// up to perhaps 3600 actions
// some of it happens in static functions declared elsewhere in the same class scope
} // this is the line mentioned in the Exception

}
```

I will be happy to any answers to some of my questions:

Why does the Exception happen?

Can I trust that all data are committed, or is there are real bug in C#.NET that allows partial commits?

Is my code correct, or should I organize it differently to work around the problem?

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the time out in web.config. Moreover try to increase the pool size. Sometimes in long queries it increases the maximum thread limit.